# Text widget won't center

Tags: flutter, dart

For some reason I can't get these text widgets to center. I've tried using Center and axisalignment but nothing seems to move the text. Surprisingly to me, the image centers itself. What do I need to change to make the text widgets align to center?

````
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
           child: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
               showImage(),
               showDate(),
               showName()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showName() => Center(child: Container(child: showTitle(model!.name!)));
  Widget showDate() => Center(child: Container(child: showTitle(model!.dateTime!)));
  Widget showImage() => Center(child: Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .8,
    child: Image.network(model!.pathImage!)),
  );
}

Widget showTitle(String string) {
  return Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            string,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 40.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color.fromARGB(0xff, 0x00, 0x2f, 0x6c),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}```
````

Comment: are you trying to center vertical or text align? Because you can't expect to center an entire column and center every single child as that logic will not make any sense. Even worst as the image is having a dynamic height. Make sure your Column has a min size in their main axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `mainAxisAlignment` to the `Row` inside your `showTitle`

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, //Here define the position "center"
  children: <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          string,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 40.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Color.fromARGB(0xff, 0x00, 0x2f, 0x6c),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Brilliant, I could have swore I tried this but perhaps it was in the wrong spot. Thank you so much for your help! It's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your column

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
```

Comment: Thank you but no luck unfortunately. I added it to just after Column( and it still wouldn't center. I've tried many solutions and none seem to move the text. It's like it is somehow fixed to the left. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try covering column with Expanded()

Comment: First wrap column with Container(color: red) then try it on every child, and see which one is not expanded

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your `Container` has not height and width. Try add width and height to your `Container`.

```dart
child: Container(
  width: 30.0,
  height: 30.0,
  child: Text(...),
),
```